# Deploying Rails on dreamhost shared server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler, dreamhost

Im trying to deploy my Rails app on dreamhost shared server. Been following this article

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/14/deploying-rails-on-dreamhost-with-passenger/

But in the last step ,

```
cap deploy:migrations
```

i get this error

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
```

First time I am trying to deploy rails app ever so im pretty lost..

Comment: Googling `capistrano could not find rake` yields 3 near duplicates from this site.  Did you try the information in those?

Comment: In addition to what Ken said, those instructions are somewhat outdated. Check Dreamhost's own support resources if you haven't already.

Comment: You are right there is quite a few hits on this subject, tried following a few ones but no luck. Since the guide is like 3 years old I hope someome might have some newer experience with this

Comment: That's fine but you need to indicate what you have tried and the result.

Comment: Oh and the dreamhost support i found this http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano which I suspect also is old?

Comment: I tried adding gem 'rake', '0.9.2' to my gemfile, nothing changed. I also tried ssh in my /realese/somedate folder and ran rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate
which came out with this error Could not find multi_json-1.1.0 in any of the sources

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because the gem binaries are not on the path.

Modify your `config/deploy.rb` file by adding the following line:

```
set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => "/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games"
}
```

This will add your gems to the path.

You can verify that this works by running `cap shell`, and typing `which rake`.  It should return the path of the Rake binary if it worked.